# Create dynamic search box autocomplete and auto submit with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Edit** I am only looking for the overview or the big picture on how best to approach this in creating a dynamic search box.

I would like to create a dynamic search box with Javascript.
The search box will show suggestions as user type (autocomplete function) and once user select the suggestion it will auto submit to the result page (onchange function?). 
This is just like Google search box.
What is the best way to do this ?
Currently I am using HTML datalist, onchange function and somehow link the event handler to a new result page.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I think you might need to do some research since you don't really have a specific coding issue. Maybe google: **Create a dynamic search box**

Comment: Hi guys Actually I am looking for the big picture, how best to approach this. The detail and Code itself I will handle it :)

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery with the AutoSuggest plugin.

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/autocomplete

Include the JS libraries (see the documentation above), then do this in HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="n1" />
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="n2" />
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="n3" />
<input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="n4" />
```

Then add an Autocomplete to the CSS-class in your Javascript:

```
var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete(data);
```